# Best type of switch for very small and sensitive signals

Tags: jfet, lna

I have an H-bridge connected to a piezoelectric ceramic transducer which feeds it 40kHz 38V AC. After 3 full oscillations, it is stopped and it starts waiting for an echo, which is probably going to be millivolt level.

The echo signal will be amplified by TP2311 op-amp, which is then fed on to the STM32 MCU's ADC and processed. The voltage and noise levels are not known, but I have some sense of those. There isn't going to be a lot of noise, because this is designed for outdoor use, and the PCB is located inside a grounded chassis and has been designed with proper grounding and will be battery powered.

The problem here is that the op-amp can't withstand 38V so there has to be some sort of switch connecting and disconnecting the non-inverting input to the piezo ceramic.

The switch has to be able to reliably carry the very small echo signal from the piezo to the op-amp without degrading it. My question is: what kind of switch fits this description? Currently I have a JFET, but I'm not 100% sure about it.

[image: schematic]

Comment: What is the source impedance of the signal? Its frequency and/or desired settling time? Why not use input protection like resistor+diode? If you want to use a switch, then it must mean what controls the switch also controls whether the small signal or +38V is applied?

Comment: ChatGPT =! Electrical engineering.

Comment: @bobflux I am not able to measure the impedance anytime soon, but the frequency is 40kHz and the settling time would be about 150uS.  Would you mind sending a simple schematic in order to show how the circuit with resistor+diode input protection would be like? The microcontroller controls when +38V is applied and when not. Thanks for the response.

Comment: This needs more schematics of your circuit

Comment: @bobflux I added the schematic, however this is not it in its entirety, because the project in itself is large and beyond the scope of this thread.

Comment: That answers the source impedance. So the actual question is: how to use the low side MOSFET RdsON as current sense, while blanking the high voltage pulse. How much current consumption can you tolerate?

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a series resistor and clamping diode(s) like everyone else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SO8 dual FET can't dissipate more than about 2W (with a small heat sink on top). For the 120mOhm PMOS in your dual MOSFET this means maximum current of 4A. On the 58 mOhm NMOS this translates to 0.232V.

To scale this for the input of a 3V3 ADC you need a gain of 14 in the opamp.

If you intend to use the H-bridge at a much lower current and set the ADC fullscale accordingly, then you need more opamp gain.

MOSFET RdsON has a strong dependence on temperature, so the measurement will not be accurate. A sense resistor would be much more accurate.

[image]

A simple solution is to use diodes and a current limiter resistor to protect the input of the opamp. However the opamp will clip into the positive rail, which means its input offset may exhibit a long recovery time which is not compatible with the desired 150µs settling time. It depends on the model of opamp. It's possible to fix this by adding some series diode in parallel with the feedback resistor, but you will lose a bit of output range.

A second solution is to short the input signal when it is not needed, which ensures the input does not clip. The small signal MOSFET M3 can be driven directly from a MCU GPIO.

In order to switch a FET or a JFET, the gate must be charged, which means the source must be connected somewhere that allows the path for gate current to be closed. Here the source of the switch is connected to ground, so it will switch quickly and without trouble.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. The H-bridge oscillates a piezoelectric ceramic at 40kHz. When the sound waves echo back the voltage generated on the pad is very small, which will be amplified by the op-amp and I think that R5 and R6 will be too noisy.  Also I can't short the op-amp input to ground. I want maximum power delivery to the piezo. My original question was, what kind of electrically controlled switch would be the best for connecting and disconnecting the non-inverting input of the amplifier to the piezo, while minimally degrading the small voltage created by the echo.

Comment: You should have given this information in the question

Comment: @boblux I'm sorry, didn't think it was necessary.

Comment: I think everyone in the comments believed you wanted to use the bottom FET as current sense (me too lol). Try to rework the question and put all the info, like what's the amplitude of the signal, maximum noise, etc. Also I asked for settling time, but if you want to measure an echo, it's an AC signal, so settling time is not relevant, I guess the 150µs is the time it takes to switch from driving the piezo to listening? Anyway you have to clear things up

Comment: Made changes, please let me know if there is still something unclear. I'd rather not waste another 5 hours.

Comment: @epicMan123 *Also I can't short the op-amp input to ground. I want maximum power delivery to the piezo.* At 38V, a 47kohm load resistor will dissipate 31mW of power. I don't think it'd be much of a concern. And it's not as if the power will be robbed away from the piezo. The H-bridge driving the piezo has such a low impedance that the additional load resistance won't measurably affect anything at all, other than a minuscule increase in the battery discharge rate.

Comment: To get the same noise spec as the opamp (8nV/rtHz) would need a few kOhms resistor which is still practical. The resistor could be replaced with a N-MOSFET for lower noise. NJFET would be on constantly with gate at zero volts so it would need a negative voltage to turn off, and PJFET gate source voltage requirements are not a good fit.

Comment: @bobflux Wouldn't the resistors in series with the non-inverting input create a voltage drop in the very sensitive signal?

Comment: It will make a lowpass filter with the opamp's input capacitance, but the cutoff frequency is high enough for it not to matter

Comment: @bobflux I got it now. Thanks so much for your help!